# Is there a way to reverse view my md5 hash code?

Tags: python-3.x

Can I do it in opposite way? I want to try viewing the `num` and `let` from my hash output.

Here's my code:

```
import hashlib

num = 20.50123851234
let = 'AAAAA'

data = '{0:.13f}:{1}'.format(num, let)
md5= hashlib.md5(data.encode('utf-8'))
hash_1 = md5.hexdigest()
print('Hash:{}'.format(hash_1, ))
```

Output:

> Hash:c0f054206e6e96f28b0654e4623a095f

Comment: No easy way, you'll have to use brute force and possibly rainbow tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of [cryptographic hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is to make what you are trying to do if not impossible, at least wholly impractical. It is their whole purpose. For illustration, what are you doing is exactly what a hacker would do to hashed password to reveal the real password.

From wiki:

> It is a mathematical algorithm that maps data of arbitrary size (often called the "message") to a bit string of a fixed size (the "hash value", "hash", or "message digest") and **is a one-way function**, that is, a function which is practically infeasible to invert. **Ideally, the only way to find a message that produces a given hash is to attempt a brute-force search of possible inputs** to see if they produce a match, or use a rainbow table of matched hashes.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Didactic answer, nice one. You might want to mention this is supposedly nearly impossible mathematically speaking, but you could give it a try with dictionaries or brute force